# Modally presented view causes previous view to disappear when navigating away/to with tab bar view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift3, uitabbarcontroller

I'm working on `UITabBarController` based app.  The app has a concept of "user authentication/restriction" where particular tabs may become restricted/unrestricted at any point in time (via an admin).

When restricted, a "authentication" view is presented over the tab's current view.  This is done simply via storyboard segue ways and is presented with "Kind" of "Present Modally" and "Presentation" of "Over current content"

Everything works just fine so long as the user doesn't navigate to a different tab while the "authentication" view is presented and back again after authorisation has been granted, in this case, the presenting view is blank

In its present form, I'm using the authentication view's `viewDidLoad` to check if the user is restricted or not, if they aren't, I'm triggering a return segue to the parent view, this means if the tab was restricted, but becomes unrestricted, the authentication view can be dismissed automatically

[image: Normal View]
[image: Authorisation Requested]
[image: Navigate away and back again]
[image: Blank View]

So, the sequence of events

1. User navigates to a "possibly restricted" tab/view
2. Restriction state requires authentication, the authentication view is presented
3. The user navigates to a different tab and back again and enters the authentication (or restrictions are lifted) and the authentication view is dismissed
4. Parent view is blank

I'm at a lose at how to resolve this.

I've tried (in the unwind segue method of the parent view)

- `view.setNeedsLayout()` and `view.setNeedsDisplay()` in the parent view in response to the segue event from the authentication view
- I've tried `navigationController?.popToViewController(self, animated: false)`
- I've tried popping and pushing the view again
- I've tried `table.reloadData()` (yes, the parent view is just a `UITableViewController`)
- I've tried removing and re-adding the `view`, but probably did it wrong

I'm at a wits end in trying to get the view controller to perform a full refresh/reload

## Update

I've been able to devise "a" solution, basically when `viewWillDisappear` is called on the authentication view, I perform a special "unauthorised dismissal" segue, the intention of which is to tell the parent view that the authentication view has been dismissed, but no authentication took place, letting it know that it should not try and update itself, but also not try and re-authenticate.

This allows the parent's `viewDidAppear` method to handle the authentication process again once it's made visible.

It works for me, but I'm open for more ideas

Comment: I'd love to know what's wrong with question that it would deserve a downvote - if the answer is so obvious to you, then please do leave a comment or answer because it's confusing as hell to me